# Does Feywild Caretaker's 2nd ability trigger only once if you have copies of it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I don't know if I get a Faerie Dragon from each copy of [Feywild Caretaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Feywild%20Caretaker) I control if I have the initiative, or if I only get one regardless of how many I have.

Answer (score 5):

Each instance of the ability triggers separately, so you get one Faerie Dragon for each Feywild Caretaker. In fact, if you could somehow give two copies of the ability to the same Feywild Caretaker, that one Fewild Caretaker would give you two Faerie Dragon.